# Can I safely remove the index.html file in every directory within codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Every sub directory inside the directories 'application' and 'system' in my codeingiter web application has an index.html file. Inside this HTML file there is what looks to be a standard error message. It contains this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I assume these are created so that if anyone tried to visit a directory inside either 'application' or 'system' it wouldn't list all the files, but would instead show an error.

These seem redundant though as I have added an .htaccess in each directory to deny all access. Every PHP file in those two directories also has the first line:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

Which should mean that no one can view any of those files at all (as I am protected once by the .htaccess and once by that line of PHP).

Therefore my question is - in the interest of keeping my web application organised and clutter free, can I safely remove these index.html files? Will this cause any bad side effects to my codeigniter web application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a plain workaround for misconfigured mod_index and directory access permissions. It's also considered security-by-obscurity, as frameworks usually leave other tracks. If there is autorunning global code in any distributed .php scripts, then that's the actual security woe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, you can remove them.

but even if you have proper rights in place, you should have them there. as they are there on only purpose, in case, you forgot to implement proper directory browsing rights

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but being my first experience with a framework I'm slightly anxious about fiddling!

Answer (score 1):

as far as you set your `.htaccess` file,, which is not redirecting towards or have no relation with your `index.html` file, you are safe (and no use to keep) to remove your `index.html`. But you should be careful. `index.html` can help in case if you fail with your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

In general You can remove those index.html files but you need to be sure that directory index is disabled in you web server configuration.

For Apache web server you can use **Options -Indexes** either in global configuration or in .htaccess files like this:

```
<Directory /wwwdata/ >

    #disable directory index
    Options -Indexes

    #other options ...

</Directory>
```

Those index.html files in CodeIgniter prevent (in any case) directory listing wich can lead to serious security flow.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that a .htaccess and the basepath condition checks are good enough, I do not really think that having two html files in two directories really clutters anything. You can never be careful enough when putting things on the web, and the CodeIgniter guys sure would have thought about it before adding it.

I really do not see any value addition removing them, but if that is what you want to do go ahead.

Comment: It's not just two index.html files, there are about twenty in total as the application and system folders have sub directories inside them also with index.html files

Comment: Yup, I know. But what I am saying is that once you start working with codeigniter, over time, you will learn to just ignore those files and they will not bother you at all.. As for the systems folder, you really never need to go inside them unless you are making changes to the core framework. And the in application folder, over time you will become more involved with your models, controllers and views. I work with CI a lot and I no longer even realize that the index files are there anymore..

Answer (score 0):

But I suggest keeping index.html as well. Keeping index.html wont harm your application but sure it do some sort of protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that you have forbidden access to the directory with .htaccess then you can safely remove them and let your worries go away!

But in case the directory is used by PHP script for some reasons and puts something in those directories and then provides a link to a user, just for example, than it will not work properly and you will have to remove your .htaccess restrictions.

I would just recommend to leave just a blank *index.html* and when a user reaches the directory there will be just a blank page displayed.

Or you could force a user to be redirected to the main page with *index.php*, for example:

```
<?php
  header("Location: ../");
?>
```